# How to create a simple calculator on Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to implement a program that reads a string and performs mathematical operations on it.

```
addop, mulop :: Parser (Expr -> Expr -> Expr)
addop = (infixOp "+" Add) <|> (infixOp "-" Sub)
mulop = infixOp "*" Mul

int :: Parser Expr
int = do
  n <- number
  return (Lit n)

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = term `chainl1` addop

term :: Parser Expr
term = factor `chainl1` mulop

factor :: Parser Expr
factor = int <|> parens expr

run :: String -> Expr
run = runParser expr

eval :: Expr -> Int
eval ex = case ex of
   Add a b -> eval a + eval b
   Mul a b -> eval a * eval b
   Sub a b -> eval a - eval b
   Lit n   -> n

evExpr :: String -> Maybe Integer
evExpr [] = Nothing
evExpr str = Just (eval (run str))
```

But I have error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Integer’

  Expected type: Maybe Integer
    Actual type: Maybe Int
• In the expression: Just (eval (run str))
  In an equation for ‘evExpr’: evExpr str = Just (eval (run str))
   |
37 | evExpr str = Just (eval (run str))
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘SourceName
                       -> [Char] -> Either ParseError Expr’
                 with ‘Expr’
  Expected type: String -> Expr
    Actual type: () -> SourceName -> [Char] -> Either ParseError Expr
• Probable cause: ‘runParser’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: runParser expr
  In an equation for ‘run’: run = runParser expr
   |
26 | run = runParser expr
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When the program is working correctly, I should see like this:

•  evExpr “27-(6*3+5%2)” = Just 8

Help me please. Thank you

Comment: As for me, the compiler accurately described the errors. What's not clear?

Comment: What's `Expr`? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `eval` returns an `Int`, but in `evExpr` you are trying to shove that `Int` into a `Maybe Integer` (based upon the type signature of `evExpr`).  An `Int` is not an `Integer`, so you get an error.  You can either change `eval` to return an `Integer`, change `evExpr` to return a `Maybe Int`, or convert the `Int` into an `Integer` with `fromIntegral`.

The second error is occurring because `runParser` has a type signature:

```
runParser :: GenParser tok st a -> st -> SourceName -> [tok] -> Either ParseError a
```

But you are calling it with a `Parser Expr` and a `String`, and left out the `SourceName` and `st` parameters.

I'm guessing that your parser doesn't have any user state, so you could use:

```
parse :: Stream s Identity t => Parsec s () a -> SourceName -> s -> Either ParseError a
```

Which doesn't require the user state (since it has type `()`), but still requires you to pass a name for the source.  Something like:

```
run :: String -> Either ParseError Expr
run = parse expr "<string>"
```

The next problem you're going to run into is that `run` can't return an `Expr` if the parser encounters a parse error.  The parser returns an `Either ParserError Expr`, which you'll have to deal with in `evExpr`.  In fact, there's no point in checking for an empty list/`String` in `evExpr`, since the parser will handle it (and generate an error).  You're better off changing `evExpr` to return an `Either ParseError Int`, and just `fmap` the `eval` over the parser result.

```
evExpr :: String -> Either ParseError Int
evExpr str = eval <$> run str
```